# What is the max number of rows allowed in the free version (or community)?

Tags: iccube

What is the maximum number of rows allowed in the free version (or community)?

I tried with 1.4 million but the cube never deployed.

Thanks.

Comment: You might try using floats (32bits) instead of double (64bits) and reduce the size of your dimension

Answer (score 2):

From https://www.iccube.com/prices/, the limit of Community version is calculated by size of data not rows. Your data of each row may different so you can't know how many rows extractly.

[image]